# Tfs workspace mapping to wrong folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am using TFS 2012.I used command line to create workspace and map it to a folder.But i got some error after creating workspace by using this.Error is that

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE"
tf workspace /noprompt /new mynewworkspace;"myusername" /server:"http://pc1:8080/tfs/newcollection"
tf workfold /map "$\newproject/Quick setup" "\\pc100\desktop\new" /server:"http://pc1:8080/tfs/newcollection" /workspace:mynewworkspace
tf get /recursive "\\pc100\desktop\new"
```

After running these workspace "mynewworkspace" created but folders mapped are not proper.

When i checked details of mapping in team explorer  the workspace had two mapping instead of one.

First one was "$/"(source control folder) mapped to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE"(local folder)

and

"$\newproject/Quick setup" (source control folder) mapped to "\pc100\desktop\new"

I dont know why the first mapping occured(that is "$/"(source control folder) mapped to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE"(local folder)) which was not there in my commands.

So please help me on this. what is wrong in my commands?

So after this i deleted workspace from the tfs so that mapping to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE" will delete. but now if run command to create new workspace

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE"
tf workspace /noprompt /new mynewworkspace;"myusername" /server:"http://pc1:8080/tfs/newcollection"
```

then error comes like "The path C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE is already mapped in workspace mynewworkspace"

But actually i have deleted the workspace before itself. So what should i do now to solve both two problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new workspace (using the tf workspace command) it maps it to the current working directory.

If you get rid of the /noprompt you will be prompted and able to change this.

See the relevant documentation here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> To make the current directory a working folder for an existing workspace on your computer, type tf workspace workspacename, where workspacename is the name of the existing workspace. The Edit Workspace dialog box appears. Click click here to enter a new working folder, type the server path for which you want to map the current directory in the Source Control Folder box, type the current directory in the Local Folder box, and click OK.

Comment: Hi Dylan smith.. So how can i create a workspace which is mapped to different directory(not current directory)? Please give me the command example. Because tf will be it's path. so i need to change directory to the path containing tf.exe. so how to create workspace mapped to another folder?

Comment: set the current directory to where you want your workspace, then just fully specify the path to tf.exe (e.g. C:\foo> c:\windows\tf.exe workspace /add ... )

Comment: ok. If i am using a path in network PC then how can i set current directory to network path? If i am doing it by using GUI then i can set path to network.So i think there should be some method or command for this also.Please help me on this

Comment: see better solution here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e5bdfd01-efa2-4944-8b6c-535d4e353b30/tfs-workspace-mapping-to-wrong-folder